# Anomaly detection using exponential weighted moving average

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

I would like to detect anomaly using exponential weighted moving average.

For an instance of time t, I will be having the data point (DP) value. 
 The EWMA constant will be 0.85 (assuming).
For Eg,

```
Time(t) DataPoint(t)    EMA(t-1)    EMA(t)  
1       120               0          102    
.        .                .           . 
.        .                .           . 
.        .                .           . 
.        .                .           . 
.        .                .           .     
10      300              150        277.5
```

I don't want to take series of data points into calculation.

At any time instance say 10, I want to know whether the data point 300 (in this case) is an anomaly or not. I also have the EMA<sub>(9)=150</sub> and EMA(10)=277.5 for calculation (if needed)

Is there any logic to calculate this?

Thanks in advance!

---

Update:

I thought of the below logic but not sure whether it would work for sure

**ABS(DP-EMA(new))> 3 *SD {EMA(old),EMA(new)}**

(or)

**ABS(DP-EMA(new))> 3 *EMWSD {EMA(old),EMA(new)}**

DP - Data Point
EMA - Exponential Weighted Moving Average

Comment: Can you tell me how you decided that 3 coefficient? And do you have any better formula?

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to say that the DP is or is not an anomaly because you don't know how developed your `EMA(t-1)` is. i.e. if there are many data points that made it then it will be a better marker than if there is only one other data point.

One approach you could take is have a change threshold. Basically if the `EMA` changes more than a percentage you consider it an anomaly. This however suffers if your numbers are all really high and the differences are really small.

What you really need is a standard deviation to detect anomalies. You could look into potentially tracking that as well and use that to better determine if you have an anomaly.

If you have any knowledge of the data that you'll be working with, update your question to get more targeted help.

**UPDATE:**

In response to the data you added I'm assuming you want 300 to be an anomaly (your other values were 120 and 150). The method I suggested above will work however if the number after 300 is more normal, say 170 that would probably also be flagged as an anomaly.

IMHO the weight you're putting on new values is excessive. I would do the other way around:

> new = .85 * old + .15 * newDP

rather than what you have of

> new = .15 * old + .85 * newDP

If you change to what I suggest you'll get fair results. Depending on what your overall goal is fair results may be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated the question with some sample data..Any suggestions now?

Comment: OK updated my answer. Should have asked this before but is there any reason that you can't keep a record?

Comment: Reasons why I have not keeping record
1.I have to take into consideration the old values from the start of the time series, 
2.I don't want a window based model.
3.Also I don't want to fetch the entire data series for each instance of time for calculation

I was wondering whether the following logic would actually work but not sure
Anomaly is true if:
ABS(DP-EMA(new))> 3 *SD {EMA(old),EMA(new)} 
(or)
ABS(DP-EMA(new))> 3 *EMWSD {EMA(old),EMA(new)} 

DP - Data Point
EMA - Exponential Weighted Moving Average

Comment: For what you're trying to do that is the logic I would use. I would go with the second equation. There are shortcomings to that way of doing it but it should be a descent way to detect anomalies.

Comment: @wckd Hello, I implemented the first formula but ABS(DP-EMA(new)) is always equals to half of 3 *SD {EMA(old),EMA(new)}. Is there a case for this? Why is that? Thanks,

Comment: @wckd And how can we calculate the EMWSD? I could not find any resource, could you give the formula or at least a link please?